# MySQL Error "Can't read dir"

Tags: mysql

I'm getting the following error when I run SHOW TABLES query,

```
mysql> show tables;
ERROR 1018 (HY000): Can't read dir of './list/' (errno: 12)
```

Can anyone explain me what is causing this ?

My datadir is /opt/data.

Thanks.

Comment: What operating system are you using? What are the permissions for /opt/data ?

Comment: @blueben permisson problems would be `errno: 13` I think

Comment: Can you add the output of `ls -al /opt/data` ?

Answer (score 1):

That `errno: 12` usually indicates an  `Out of memory` Error.
Check your available Memory.